# Javascript remove duplicate in a list of objects merging some properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, ramda.js

I have this list:

```
const debts = [
  {
    amount: 10,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "John"
  },
  {
    amount: 20,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "John"
  },
  {
    amount: 10,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "Tom"
   }
];
```

...and I want to merge the elements with the same debtor and creditor calculating the total amount, like this

```
const debts = [
  {
    amount: 30, // 10 + 20
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "John"
  },
  {
    amount: 10,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "Tom"
   }
];
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're interested in a solution using Ramda, here's a suggestion:

```js
const {
  pipe,
  mergeWithKey,
  map,
  reduce,
  values,
  groupBy,
  props,
  join
} = R;

const debts = [{
    amount: 10,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "John"
  },
  {
    amount: 20,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "John"
  },
  {
    amount: 10,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "Tom"
  }
];

const mergeAmount = mergeWithKey((key, left, right) => key === 'amount' ? left + right : left);
const groupKey = pipe(props(['debtor', 'creditor']), join(' ~> '));

const process =
  pipe(
    groupBy(groupKey),
    map(reduce(mergeAmount, {})),
    values);

console.log(process(debts));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

---

The idea is to split the process in three steps:

1. Group debtors and creditors together
2. For each debtor/creditor group, merge the amount
3. Extract each debtor/creditor group into an array

#### Step 1: groupBy(groupKey)

*Step 1 gets the original `debts` array*

```
{
    "Mark ~> John": [
        {
            amount: 10,
            creditor: "John",
            debtor: "Mark"
        },
        {
            amount: 20,
            creditor: "John",
            debtor: "Mark"
        }
    ],
    "Mark ~> Tom": [
        {
            amount: 10,
            creditor: "Tom",
            debtor: "Mark"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Step 2: map(reduce(mergeAmount, {}))

*Step 2 gets the output from step 1*

```
{
    "Mark ~> John": {
        amount: 30,
        creditor: "John",
        debtor: "Mark"
    },
    "Mark ~> Tom": {
        amount: 10,
        creditor: "Tom",
        debtor: "Mark"
    }
}
```

#### Step 3: values

*Step 3 gets the output from step 2*

```
[
    {
        amount: 30,
        creditor: "John",
        debtor: "Mark"
    },
    {
        amount: 10,
        creditor: "Tom",
        debtor: "Mark"
    }
]
```

Comment: Slightly cleaner, perhaps, would be `map(reduce(mergeAmount, {amount: 0}))` for the second step.

Comment: Interesting, as my own solution was almost identical except for the comment above and the inlining of what you call `groupKey`.  And, this is very interesting, I invert the order of your last two steps; it works either way.  I actually think Ramda needs a function something like `(fn) => (list) => values(groupBy(fn, list))`.  It's such a common combination.

Comment: I agree this is cleaner. Not sure what I was thinking but `converge` wasn't necessary. All I was saving is just one iteration at the cost of readability. Thanks!

Comment: You can convert `map(reduce(mergeAmount, {amount: 0}))` to `map(reduce(mergeAmount, {}))` because if the key doesn't exist in both `mergeWithKey` doesn't use the callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object with key as unique pair of debtor and creditor and value as resulting object. In case there is an existing entry for the pair in object, increment the amount else add a new entry in object.

Finally, use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/object/values) to collect all the objects.

```js
let debts = [{amount: 10,debtor: "Mark",creditor: "John"},{amount: 20,debtor: "Mark",creditor: "John"},{amount: 10,debtor: "Mark",creditor: "Tom"}];

let result = Object.values(debts.reduce((a,c) => {
  let key = `${c.debtor}~~${c.creditor}`;
  if(a[key]) a[key].amount += c.amount;
  else a[key] = Object.assign({},c);
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looks great, why do you used `a[key] = Object.assign({},c)` instead of `a[key] = c`?

Comment: @SergioP - Objects are passed by reference and whenever `a[key].amount += c.amount;` the object is modified. I wanted to avoid overwriting the object in the array

Answer (score 1):

Use the `filter()` function to iterate through the resulting list and check if the debtor-creditor pair already exist. If it exists, then updates the amount. Otherwise, add it as a new entry in the resulting list.

```js
const debts = [
  {
    amount: 10,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "John"
  },
  {
    amount: 20,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "John"
  },
  {
    amount: 10,
    debtor: "Mark",
    creditor: "Tom"
  }
];

var result = []
debts.forEach((item) => {
  var existing = result.filter((resultItem, index) => {
    return resultItem.debtor === item.debtor && resultItem.creditor === item.creditor;
  });

  if (existing.length) {
    var existingIndex = result.indexOf(existing[0]);
    result[existingIndex].amount += item.amount;
  } else {
    result.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(result)
```